# Activity recreation and unresumable operation

Tags: android

I wonder what is correct way for handling an unresumable running process when an activity recreates.

For example I have a JNI module for authenticating to a server. I have created a new instance of this object in `OnCreateView()` of my activity, setting up some callback routines for it. Now by pressing a button, I start my authentication process asynchronously. Authentication is just 1 sec, but if my activity recreate during authentication process(for example I switch from portrait to landscape), my JNI object will be recreated and mess authentication process up. I cannot save state of authentication process.

Now what do you suggest for such situations? An idea is running authentication process in a service, completely separated from activity recreation. I wonder if there is any other simpler approach or not.

Comment: I think the good practise is to use "retained fragment" with none-UI to hold your process. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc this seems interesting. I need to check it thoroughly. :) Does this method works when you go out of app by pressing home and returning to it quickly?(as another recreation situation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add configChanges to your activity in Manifest.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.yourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: I used screen orientation as an example and this approach may solve that one. But this is not a generic solution for activity recreation. if I press home and then quickly return to app, this is another activity recreation that cannot be solved with this approach. I need a more generic method.

Comment: Then override onConfigurationChanged and do what ever you need

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to recreate the Activity when orientation changed?

If not, then you can do what @Naveen suggested which will not re create your Activity.